# Need help repeating a function for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

http://pastebin.com/32nitzwy#

here is the pastebin with the function

I am unfamiliar with javascript so I need help repeating this function.

Instead of exiting after 1 run of this function I want it to run this function repeatedly forever.

Comment: use the setInterval method :)

Comment: can you show me an example of that setInterval, I am really ignorant when it comes to programming sorry.

Comment: while(1){//call func; if(some-condition) break;}

Comment: Here is infor for setInterval https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could encapsulate everything in the function with a while loop, like this

```
function DupeReroll() {
    while(true){

    //Existing script

}}
```

To make it run only 30 times, use a for loop instead.

```
function DupeReroll() {
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        //Existing script
}}
```

Comment: This also blocks the whole Browser/Tab and makes the site completly unresponsive. The only thing how you can break out of it is to close Browser/Tab. That is often not what someone ever wants.

Comment: this isn't a browser application, its a script for a diablo 3 bot so it dosent matter in this case, but otherwise you are right.

Comment: Oh do  you happen to know how to make the function run only 30 times?

Comment: Sure, but thats not the question. Instead of a while loop, use a for loop. i've added it to my answer.

Comment: oh i see so i only change the #30 to w/e i want and it will repeat the loop that many times? btw the loops working tyvm. i wanna thank everyone else who has commented it means a lot.

Comment: I got another question for the second answer. It repeats the function that many times but after it will not run the function below it. Do you know what I can put to continue reading the rest of the function?

Comment: actually for (i=0; i < 30; i++){ seems to continue a loop as well

Answer (score 0):

Just by using this :

```
setInterval(myFunc(), 3000);
```

The method will be called in 3 seconds and if you place this statement inside myFunc() it will run forever every 3 seconds

Comment: Oh thank you that is very clear. I also had a question because this function at the end makes the function stop. At what line should I remove to keep that from occurring. It's found in line 606 
while(!leave) { 

607.
                delay(1000); 

608.
        }

Comment: If you don't want delay just use the `while(true)` loop like posted :)

Comment: That example is wrong in enomerous ways. `setInterval()` already repeatedly calls a function. Calling `setInterval` again in `myFunc` is not what you want. What you want instead is `setTimeout` not `setInterval`. And the last error is that you just want to specifiy `myFunc` not `myFunc()`. The last one executes `myFunc` and the return value is passed to `setInterval()`. If the return value of myFunc() is not another function, your code will break.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
setTimeout(myFunc, 3000);
```

The function `myFunc` will be called after 3 seconds one time. If you repeatedly want to call a function forever, then use `setInterval` instead.

```
setInterval(myFunc, 3000);
```

This now runs `myFunc` every 3 seconds. Sometimes you want to run something repeatedly but still be able to stop it in the future. `setInterval` returns you a value so clear the Interval.

```
var id = setInterval(myFunc, 3000);
...
// Somewehere in the future
clearinterval(id);
```

Note to just provide `myFunc` and not `myFunc()`. You need to provide a reference to a function. You get it with just specifing the function without the `()`. If you add the braces then the function `myFunc()` will be executed and the return value will be used for `setInterval`.  If `myFunc` does not return a function then this code will break.

You also can use an infinite `while` loop. But often that is not what you want. You usally still want to execute other code and your site should still react. With `setTimeout` and `setInterval` you can definie a function that runs asynchronously without blocking your site.